# What does "No possibility to remove or change the metadataXml once it is added" mean?

Tags: tom.net

I have a use case where I need to add custom page metadata on publish (preferably via a TBB) as per point 2 of Dom's answer here: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/3917/159.  In essence, this is a perfect for the use of the `Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.AddMetadata` method on the `RenderedItem` (see "SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 TOM.NET API.chm").

The API states:

> There is no possibility to remove or change the metadataXml once it is
>   added.

What does this mean exactly?

1. Does it mean that once it gets written into the Broker's tables, you can't change it upon subsequent republishes?
2. Or does it mean that once its in the Broker, you can't change the meta keys, but can still change the meta values associated?
3. Or some other reason?

Comment: I suspect this may end up as a "What have you tried?". Write some code: become the world's top expert!!

Comment: I am pretty sure the AddMetadata method doesnt add metadata in the sense of custom metadata which gets written into the broker, I think its just metadata which is available somewhere in the transport package, but its not actually written to the broker DB, unless you create some extension to do it

Comment: Yeah Will - someone recently told me that, but I was sure I remembered using this API in the obvious way. Now I'm going to have to write code.....

Comment: As far as I can tell, I was correct to think I'd used AddMetadata without having to customise CD. The only trouble is that this was the AddMetadata in the old TOM, and not the one in TOM.NET - so apparently the "new" version has a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `RenderedItem.AddMetaData()` during publishing just adds custom XML into the transport package for that item. It's available for use on the deployer side, but it's **not** written into the content data store like an item's actual metadata.

See http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/10/rendereditem-metadata-and-instruction.html for a little more info.

I'm currently using RenderedItem metadata to push the publishing user's information to the content delivery for use in a deployer extension. I believe the metadata is available as a string via the `getRenderAddedMetaData()` methods on the `com.tridion.transport.transportpackage.Page` and `com.tridion.transport.transportpackage.ComponentPresentation` objects.

I think that "There is no possibility to remove or change the metadataXml once it is added" just means that you can set some custom XML for the RenderedItem, but you cannot access it in the TOM.Net API once set.